# QComboBox findText fails to find QString

Tags: qt, qt5

Here is my code:

```
const QString k_NoFilter = "No Filter";
const QString k_Filter1 = "UV filter";

QStringList filters;
filters << k_NoFilter << k_Filter1;

ui.comboFilter->addItems(filters);
int ix = ui.comboFilter->findText(k_NoFilter);
ui.comboFilter->setCurrentIndex(ix);
```

I can't get the index. It always is -1. What might be wrong?

Comment: Doesn't even work when i remove the constant and try to findText with the literal, i.e. ->findText("No Filter")

Comment: I ran your code, and I got ix=0. There must be something else.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I thought it should work. I will find it and update for closure.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the string for the item is stored by Qt in a weird way. It is ended with two white spaces (maybe '\r' and '\n').